# Django URLconf changes itself strangely

Tags: django, admin, django-urls

Here is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'halo.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^halo/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),                            
)
```

Most of time,I can visit example.com/halo/admin.But sometimes,it shows a 404 error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in halo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
$admin/
The current URL, halo/admin/, didn't match any of these.
```

It's strange,because there is no '$admin/' in my urls.py.

Comment: You should keep in mind that, django/python or any kind of programming language can't change or modify itself. Problem is with your code. According to your code you have to use xxx.com/halo/admin/ to access admin site, so using xxx.com/halo/admin will not help here. Urlconfig can't change itself.

Comment: I know it.But,how to explain why the error page shows:$admin/
The current URL, halo/admin/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Please copy paste url you are passing into browser .

Answer (score 0):

There is a change that you are hitting wrong url from browser.

*for Example :*

```
http://example.com//halo/admin/
```

here passing // in url  can create same problem you are facing